# Implementing a load balancer (round robin) for email service on Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, queue, round-robin

I have two services for sending emails, Postmark and SendGrid. I used Factory Pattern to be expandable and flexible.

EmailProviderInterface

```
namespace App\Services\Notifications;

interface EmailProviderInterface
{
    public function sendEmail(string $to, string $templateName, array $data);
}
```

PostMarkEmailService

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Notifications;

use App\Traits\SendEmailTrait;

class PostmarkEmailService implements EmailProviderInterface
{
    use SendEmailTrait;

    /**
     * send email using postmark
     *
     * @param string $to
     * @param string $templateName
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function sendEmail(string $to, string $templateName, array $data): array
    {

        $templateInfo = $this->getHtmlRender($templateName, $data);
        if (!$templateInfo['success']) {
            return $templateInfo;
        }
        
        try {
            // implement logic calling external api and passing the html

            return $this->successHandler();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->handleErrors($e);
        }
    }
}
```

SendGridEmailService

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Notifications;

use App\Traits\SendEmailTrait;

class SendGridEmailService implements EmailProviderInterface
{

    use SendEmailTrait;


    /**
     * Send Email Using SendGrid
     *
     * @param string $to
     * @param string $templateName
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function sendEmail(string $to, string $templateName, array $data): array
    {

        $templateInfo = $this->getHtmlRender($templateName, $data);
        if (!$templateInfo['success']) {
            return $templateInfo;
        }
        try {
            // implement logic calling external api and passing the html

            return $this->successHandler();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->handleErrors($e);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is EmailServiceProvider that will use it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Notifications;

class EmailServiceProvider
{
    private EmailProviderInterface $emailProvider;

    public function __construct(bool $highPriority = true)
    {
        if ($highPriority) {
            $this->emailProvider = new PostmarkEmailService();
        } else {
            $this->emailProvider = new SendGridEmailService();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Send email using the email provider
     *
     * @param string $to
     * @param string $templateName
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function sendMail(string $to, string $templateName, array $data): array
    {
        return $this->emailProvider->sendEmail($to, $templateName, $data);
    }


}
```

I need to implement a load balancer (using a round robin strategy) with a retry mechanism. This would operate on the EmailService provider to swap between PostMark And SendGrid services.

If I were to implement a queue, how can apply such a load balancer?

Comment: You don't need to load-balance your email providers, since sending an email is not a time-sensitive task. Put an email job on a queue and then implement your try/retry there.

Comment: How can I deal with the queue if I have 2 providers (postmark & sendgrid)?

Comment: You could put two workers on the queue, one for each provider. Or if the queue has one worker, the worker can flip between providers on its own.

Comment: Why do you have/want two service providers?

Answer (score 0):

To implement Load Balacing with retries in your EmailServiceProvider, you can update `constructor` and `sendMail` method.

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Notifications;

class EmailServiceProvider
{
    private array $emailProviders;
    private int $currentProviderIndex;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->emailProviders = [
            new PostmarkEmailService(),
            new SendGridEmailService(),
        ];
        $this->currentProviderIndex = 0;
    }

    public function sendMail(string $to, string $templateName, array $data): array
    {
        $maxRetries = count($this->emailProviders);

        for ($retry = 0; $retry < $maxRetries; $retry++) {
            try {
                $provider = $this->emailProviders[$this->currentProviderIndex];
                $response = $provider->sendEmail($to, $templateName, $data);
                return $response;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->rotateProvider();
            }
        }

        return ['success' => false, 'message' => 'Failed to send email'];
    }

    private function rotateProvider(): void
    {
        $this->currentProviderIndex++;
        if ($this->currentProviderIndex >= count($this->emailProviders)) {
            $this->currentProviderIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also implement load balancing at the queue level by leveraging a message broker such as `RabbitMQ` or `Redis`.

These message brokers support load balancing mechanisms out of the box, allowing you distribute the processing of email jobs across multiple worker processes or machines.

Comment: but when using this method to send mail,

like this  --->    (new EmailServiceProvider()->sendMail('test@m.com', 'otp', ['otp' => '1234', 'user_name' => 'test user']));

 every time will make a 
new instance and Will use the Postmark Service  every time